# spring boot config application context hierarchy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I hava a problem with spring boot hiararchy application context configuration,my project is a web war,the log shows spring boot start two times,one is initiliazed by web container,one is staring with embedded container,because it should not start with embedded container, so the second time throw a exception. here is my SpringBootServletInitializer:

```
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Configuration
    public class RootConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return  application.sources(ConsoleWebApplication.class).child(WebConfig.class).web(true).sibling(AjaxConfig.class).web(true);
        }

    ......
    ......
    }
```

ConsoleWebApplication.java:

```
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
    @ComponentScan(
            basePackages = "com",
            excludeFilters =
            @ComponentScan.Filter({Controller.class, ControllerAdvice.class}))
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
    public class ConsoleWebApplication  {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ConsoleWebApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

WebConfig.java:

```
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(
            basePackages = "com",
            useDefaultFilters = false,
            includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(WebController.class)
    )
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            System.out.println("-----------------------WebConfig");
        }

        @Override
        public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
            argumentResolvers.add(new CurrentUserMethodArgumentResolver());
            super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        }

     ......
     ......
    }
```

AjaxConfig:

```
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(
             basePackages = "com",
             useDefaultFilters = false,
             includeFilters =
             @ComponentScan.Filter({AjaxController.class, AjaxControllerAdvice.class}))
    public class AjaxConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

         @PostConstruct
         public void init(){
             System.out.println("-----------------------AjaxConfig");
         }


         @Autowired
         ObjectMapper objectMapper;

         @Autowired
         Marshaller marshaller;

         @Autowired
         Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    ......
    ......
    }
```

web pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>console-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
......
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>    
......
```

tomcat start log:

```
    ......Connected to server
        [2017-07-15 07:58:06,249] Artifact web: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
        15-Jul-2017 07:58:10.295 信息 [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
        2017-07-15 07:58:11,808 INFO o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Starting RootConfig on DESKTOP-FEKUQDP with PID 11396 (H:\快盘\开发\spring\console-parent\console-web\target\console-web-1.0.0\WEB-INF\classes started by yyi in E:\webapp\apache-tomcat-8.5.16\bin)
        2017-07-15 07:58:11,818 INFO o.s.b.SpringApplication [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
        2017-07-15 07:58:12,054 INFO o.h.v.i.u.Version [background-preinit] HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final
        2017-07-15 07:58:12,231 INFO o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2d7d1b26: startup date [Sat Jul 15 07:58:12 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        2017-07-15 07:58:14,121 INFO o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
        15-Jul-2017 07:58:16.042 信息 [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [E:\webapp\apache-tomcat-8.5.16\webapps\manager]
        15-Jul-2017 07:58:16.094 信息 [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [E:\webapp\apache-tomcat-8.5.16\webapps\manager] has finished in [51] ms
        2017-07-15 07:58:16,130 INFO o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
        2017-07-15 07:58:16,798 INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Bean 'shiroConfig' of type [com.founder.console.web.config.ShiroConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a102b8d1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
        2017-07-15 07:58:16,879 INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Bean 'jpaConfig' of type [com.founder.config.JpaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c46880a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
        2017-07-15 07:58:17,197 INFO o.s.c.e.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Initializing EhCache CacheManager
        2017-07-15 07:58:17,381 INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Bean 'ehCacheManagerFactoryBean' of type [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
        2017-07-15 07:58:17,395 INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Bean 'ehCacheManagerFactoryBean' of type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        017-07-15 07:58:29,368 INFO o.s.j.e.MBeanExporter [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Located managed bean 'beansEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=beansEndpoint]
        2017-07-15 07:58:29,372 INFO o.s.j.e.MBeanExporter [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Located managed bean 'infoEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=infoEndpoint]
        2017-07-15 07:58:29,376 INFO o.s.j.e.MBeanExporter [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Located managed bean 'loggersEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=loggersEndpoint]
        2017-07-15 07:58:29,386 INFO o.s.j.e.MBeanExporter [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Located managed bean 'metricsEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=metricsEndpoint]
        2017-07-15 07:58:29,390 INFO o.s.j.e.MBeanExporter [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Located managed bean 'traceEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=traceEndpoint]
        2017-07-15 07:58:29,394 INFO o.s.j.e.MBeanExporter [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Located managed bean 'dumpEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=dumpEndpoint]
        2017-07-15 07:58:29,398 INFO o.s.j.e.MBeanExporter [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Located managed bean 'autoConfigurationReportEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=autoConfigurationReportEndpoint]
        2017-07-15 07:58:29,401 INFO o.s.j.e.MBeanExporter [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint]
        2017-07-15 07:58:29,434 INFO o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Started RootConfig in 18.43 seconds (JVM running for 24.637)

          .   ____          _            __ _ _
         /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
        ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
         \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
          '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
         =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
         :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)

        2017-07-15 07:58:30,099 INFO o.s.b.SpringApplication [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
        2017-07-15 07:58:30,103 INFO o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@234aeedc: startup date [Sat Jul 15 07:58:30 CST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2d7d1b26
        2017-07-15 07:58:30,715 WARN o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
        2017-07-15 07:58:30,724 ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] Application startup failed
        org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.runAndExtractParent(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:219) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.sibling(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:247) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
            at com.founder.console.web.config.RootConfig.configure(RootConfig.java:35) ~[classes/:?]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.16]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.16]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.16]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.16]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.16]
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1739) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.16]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.16]
            at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.16]
            at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.16]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.16]
            at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,but I haven't modified build pom.xml,next is my whole web pom.xml:
        
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            4.0.0
            console-web
            war

```
        <name>console-web</name>
        <description>Founder securities console web</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>com.founder</groupId>
            <artifactId>console</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <thymeleaf.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
            <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
            <thymeleaf-shiro.version>2.0.0</thymeleaf-shiro.version>
            <start-class>com.founder.console.web.ConsoleWebApplication</start-class>
        </properties>


        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>console-domain</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>console-service</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.theborakompanioni</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-shiro</artifactId>
                <version>${thymeleaf-shiro.version}</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>


            </plugins>
        </build>


    </project>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add some `<plugin>`. remove all of your plugins if you used and replace with the `spring-boot-maven` plugin. you can use bellow code:-

```
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

and add some more dependencies, you can get dependencies bellow

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks,but I haven't modified build pom.xml,next is my whole web pom.xml:

Comment: you can try bellow annotation before   class in `ConsoleWebApplication.java`

`@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration`.